# Screen sharing in agora broadcasting using flutter

Tags: flutter, broadcasting, agora.io, screensharing

Can someone suggest on how to implement screen sharing in flutter. one solution i was thinking of using native code for android screen stream but i m unable to find way to send it to channel.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Screen Sharing is not supported by the Agora flutter SDK also you can't push any external media source to your stream.

You can use the native SDKs provided by Agora which allows you to share your screen for both video calling as well as broadcasting.

Comment: Coudld you please give more info extaclty how can we do that?